# Why are some youtube videos not playing in chromeless player in my AS2 swf?

Tags: flash, video, actionscript-2, youtube-api

I have a Flash app that loads a list of youtube video ids. It loads a grid of thumbnails and a chromeless player into each of these thumbnail then calls cueVideoById() on each player so I now have a grid of youtube videos with the play button and youtube logo... so far so good.

What I cant work out is why when I call playVideo on these thumbnails some play and some do not. For those that dont play, all I see is a black screen and the youtube logo - though I assume this logo is part of the player. I would expect to see the loading animation if the video was loading.

Any ideas what would cause some to play fine and others to only cue and never play?

cheers all.

-------------------------------------------------- EDIT---------------------------------------

Is this simply because the owner of the video has not allowed the video to be embeded. When I search on youtube for the video I am trying to play the embed section on the right states- "Embedding disabled by request".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is that you do not have rights to access the video. (embed)

Chromeless player can only play embeddable videos.

Comment: ok so how do I exclude these when searching videos with the api?